# Does the image of automorphism equals to the image of automorphism composition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}E$ is a vector space and $f$ and $g$ are automorphisms on E such that: $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_E$ (identity mapping $E$). Prove that $\Im(g) = \Im(g \circ f)$.

So what I got here trying to prove it:

$f \circ g = id_E => g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_E $

We need to prove that: $\Im(g) = \Im(g \circ f) = \Im(\operatorname{id}_E) $

But I got stuck trying to realise how is it possible that $\Im(g)=\Im(\operatorname{id}_E)$? As far as I understand, it works only if both  automorphisms ($f$ and $g$) are trivial (identity mappings). But how could I prove it?

Comment: What's your definition of automorphism? Normally part of that definition is that it is injective and surjective....

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}E$
If $f, g$ are *automorphisms*, then everything is trivial (see Fred's answer). I think you want to consider *endomorphisms* such that $f \circ g = id_E$.

The condition $f \circ g = id_E$ implies that $f$ is surjective (if $x \in E$, then $f(g(x)) = x$) and $g$ is injective (if $g(x) = g(y)$, then $x = f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) =y$). Thus, if $E$ is finite-dimensional, then $f,g$ **must** be automorphisms, but if $E$ is infinite-dimensional, you always find examples with non-automorphisms.

However, since $f$ is surjective, the image of $g$ is always the same as that $g \circ f$:

$$\Im(g \circ f) = (g \circ f)(E) = g(f(E))) = g(E) = \Im(g) .$$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ and $g$ are bijective, thus $\operatorname{Im}(g)=E$. Since $g \circ f$ is bijective, we get $\operatorname{Im}(g \circ f)=E.$
It is clear, that $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{id}_E)=E.$

Comment: Thanks! I kinda get stuck exactly on this: "   and  are bijective, thus ()=.", seems like I need to check again what exactly bijective means for automorphism.